# objective-c accessing class variable from button selector

Tags: objective-c

I am initializing UIButton in init method of a class like this:

```
UIButton* upButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2*stepX, 13*stepY,2*stepX,stepY)];
[upButton setTitle:@"UP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[upButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[upButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In pressedUp method I need to use variables from that class (NSInteger* and my class hero*). 
So I am doing:

```
hero*h=self.mainHero;
NSInteger*m=self.map;
```

But later in code I can easily work with hero class (change position etc) but it fails to work with self.map (awful integers in array instead of 0 and 1)... How to fix it?

Comment: what's your map? Y NSInteger *m?

Comment: @ValentinKhrulkov Please show the code that initializes the `map` property. Any particular reason why you'd prefer using `NSInteger*` over `NSValue*` with an integer inside?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `@property (nonatomic) NSInteger* map;`synthesize,`NSInteger lvl1Map[]={
         1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
         1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,
         1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
     };
         [self setMap:lvl1Map];` Hmm not really,kinda new to Objective-c

Comment: @ValentinKhrulkov Forget my last coment about `NSValue*`, I did not realize that the pointer was a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a scalar `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last comment it appears that the problem is due to a dangling reference: you create a local variable `lvl1Map[]`, assign it to `self.map`, and exit the initializer. At this point, `lvl1Map[]` is gone, but the `map` is pointing to the area in the memory where it once has been.

You can fix this problem by declaring `lvl1Map` static:

```
NSInteger lvl1Map[]={...};
[self setMap:lvl1Map];
```

Comment: Oops I forgot to say that "map" property is NSInteger*